# How can you check to see if the first two letters in the ArrayList is equal to something and then increase the sum in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I made a program to do the above, but it keeps printing the sum as 0. The goal is if the string's index (0,2) is "ab" then the sum is increased by 1. So far this is what I have but it prints 0. Should my if statement be written differently to fix it?

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* declare list */
    
    System.out.println(checkAB(list));
}

public static int checkAB(ArrayList<String> list) {
    int sum  = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.subList(0,2).equals("ab")) {
            sum++
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Comment: You want to get the string from the list, then get the substring. `if (list.get(i).substring(0,2).equals("ab"))....`

Comment: Note that Java also has a `String.startsWith()` function.

Comment: Does your solution need to be case sensitive?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp and there are the `ignoreCase` functions as well if case sensitivity doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you're comparing `'List<String>'` with `'String'` on line

```
if(list.subList(0,2).equals("ab")) {
```

That isn't possible.

#### Version 1:

If I understood you correctly, try this instead (*Feel free to modify it according to your needs*):
Here, I'm only checking if the first two letters(*list values*) in the `ArrayList` are equal to `["a", "b"]`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");
        list.add("e");
        System.out.println(checkAB(list));
    }

    private static boolean checkAB(ArrayList<String> list) {
        return list.subList(0, 2).equals(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
    }
}
```

#### Version 2:

On the other hand, it appears that all you have is a *list of strings* and you
just want to count how many *list values* start with ***"ab"***.
If that is the case, please try this instead:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abdfSDhg", "bxcbd", "gjfQAZjd", "abvoo");
        System.out.println(checkAB(list));
    }

    private static long checkAB(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith("ab"))
                .count();
    }

}
```

#### Resources

Interface **List<E>**

- list.subList()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-
- list.equals()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

**Java Streams**

- stream()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html
- filter()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-
- count()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--

Good luck!